# Running Ghost module for node.js on Heroku as subdirectory

Tags: express, ghost-blog

I'm trying to install Ghost to my node app. I followed the configuration instructions and got it running with, however when I navigate to the blog subdirectory it just shows my site's homepage. I'm passing it the express app instance to start the server. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var ghost = require('ghost');
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    app.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);
    ghostServer.start(app);
    
});
```

I read online about running Ghost with ngynx or apache and configuring it to do some kind of proxy thing, but I don't really understand what all that's about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of app.js for express and ghost subdirectory setup. Notice how your express routes need to be wrapped in the ghost.then() callback.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ghost = require('ghost');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {

    app.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);
    ghostServer.start(app);

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const ghost = require('ghost')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const { getSubDir } = require('./node_modules/ghost/core/server/services/url/utils')

const app = express()
ghost().then((ghostServer) => {
  app.use('/games', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'games')))
  app.use(getSubdir(), ghostServer.rootApp)
  ghostServer.start(app)
})
```

latest howto included here:
https://docs.ghost.org/docs/using-ghost-as-an-npm-module

Comment: Please don't use the clustering config given in this answer. Ghost does not work across clusters due to in-memory caches that will result in each instance getting out of sync with each other.

Comment: removed cluster

Comment: afaik caches are for templates only

Comment: In-memory caches are used for multiple things in Ghost such as settings, routing tables, etc. it's not just templates.